# Restore ActionMode after orientation change

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have listfragment which starts actionmode. I am using actionbarsherlock. But when orientation changes, or when I start new activity contextual actionbar disapears. 
Is there any way to restore it back, without starting it again? In google gmail app it stays on screen whether I rotate phone or go to the detail screen.

Comment: check out this abs issue thread: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/463

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The better way is use onSaveInstanceState to save ActionMode state before rotation.

```
public abstract class MyActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{

    private boolean isInActionMode = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state){
         super.onCreate(state);

         if (state != null && state.getBoolean("ActionMode", false)){
                startActionMode(new MyActionMode());
         }else{
             ///whatever you'd normally do
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
         // Save isInActionMode value
         outState.putBoolean("ActionMode", isInActionMode);

         super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    public void onWhateverEventNormallyStartsYourActionMode(){
        startActionMode(new MyActionMode());
    }

    public class MyActionMode implements ActionMode.Callback{

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            isInActionMode = true;
            ///whatever you'd normally do
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            ///whatever you'd normally do
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            ///whatever you'd normally do
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            isInActionMode = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Updated according to  Saran's comment.

Comment: Should put `isInActionMode = true;` only in `onCreateActionMode()` otherwise next rotation will not pick up the state.

Comment: This does not really restore the action mode. It recreates it anew. So you have to recreate the action mode title and redo all the item selections.

Comment: Of course. You have to save state of dynamic data (selections for example) and restore it later.

Comment: A possible solution was to use `setRetainInstance()` in the fragment, that would have maintained the selections etc. But due to a bug(https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20791) when using loaders from the support library, it is practically useless.

Comment: I just realized list view selections are automatically maintained by the fragment on orientation change when using the support library(not sure about Sherlock). To prevent corruption of the selections, set the `choicemode` attribute of the `listview` layout element to `multiplechoice`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294919/maintain-item-selection-on-orientation-change/24301175#24301175.