# maintain Item selection on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I am trying to restore the state of the action mode on orientation change. But it does not work properly. Following the below sequence of steps, in #3 and #4 the selections get corrupted :

1. Long click an item - item is highlighted, contextual action bar shows with title shows "1 selected". Looks good.
2. Turn the phone to landscape - no change. Looks good.
3. Turn the phone back to portrait - item is not highlighted, contextual action bar is gone
4. Long click an item - item is highlighted, contextual action bar shows with title shows "0 selected"

`myListView.getCheckedItemCount()` in `onSaveInstanceState()` returns 0 on #3. That's where the problem starts.

What am i doing wrong in my fragment(using support library)?

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //check if any items are selected
    if (myListView.getCheckedItemCount() > 0) {
        //get the list of selected items and convert it to an int Array
        //because SparseBooleanArray cannot be stored in a bundle
        SparseBooleanArray selectedItems = myListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        int[] selectedItems_intArray = new int[myListView.getCheckedItemCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
            if (selectedItems.valueAt(i) == false)
                continue;
            selectedItems_intArray[i] = selectedItems.keyAt(i);
        }
        outState.putIntArray(KEY_CHECKED_ITEMS, selectedItems_intArray);
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        int[] checkedItems = savedInstanceState.getIntArray(KEY_CHECKED_ITEMS);
        if (checkedItems != null) {
            actionMode = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(new ContextualActionBarActionModeCallBack());

            for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++) {
                myListView.setItemChecked(checkedItems[i], true);
            }

            actionMode.setTitle(myListView.getCheckedItemCount() + " selected");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    myListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    adpt = new myCustomCursorAdapter(getActivity());
    myListView.setAdapter(adpt);
    //Choice mode is allowed only after a long click
    //disabling it on first time load
    myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
        myListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            if(actionMode == null){
                //Start the action mode
                actionMode = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(new ContextualActionBarActionModeCallBack());

                myLisVIew.setItemChecked(position, true);                           
                actionMode.setTitle(myListView.getCheckedItemCount() + " selected");
                return true;
                }
            else return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);
}

private class ContextualActionBarActionModeCallBack implements ActionMode.Callback{
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mycontextmenu, menu);   
        myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

**ListView layout element :**

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/layout_input"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that the choice mode of the list view is being reset to a default of `CHOICE_MODE_NONE` every time the list view is created on orientation change because a choice mode has not been explicitly defined in the list view layout file. The Android source where this happens - http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java#815.

The solution is to add :

```
android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
```

to the list view layout.

This also means that there is no need to manually store the list view selections in `onSaveInstanceState()` and retrieve it in `onViewStateRestored()`. It is done automatically by the fragment. So remove both these functions. Just start the action mode in `onResume` :

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);
            if (myListView.getCheckedItemCount() > 0 && actionMode == null) {
            actionMode = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(new ContextualActionBarActionModeCallBack());
            actionMode.setTitle(myListView.getCheckedItemCount() + " selected");
        }
    }
```

**Note :** If you have implemented the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallBacks` interface and you need to access the adaptor items just after orientation change, do it in `onLoadFinished()` after the adaptor has been loaded with the data source. Doing it in `onResume()` would cause an `NPE`.

Comment: my activity and fragment not recreating on orientation change because i'm using android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" so listview also should not recreate.